# Add extra key-value pair in 'project' in MongoDB aggregate functionality using spring mongo template

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mongodb

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
                    match(criteria),
                    group("username").count().as("userCount"),
                    project("userCount").and("_id").as("user")
            );

   AggregationResults<MyTarget> dataObjects = mongoTemplate
            .aggregate(agg, <collectionName>, MyTarget.class);
```

In above example, I have one more field say - 'extraField' - in `MyTarget` class which can be assigned one of the few predefined values (let us say - "abc" and "xyz"). I know this value prior to hitting the MongoDB.

How can I add this extra key-value ["extraField" : "abc"]pair into projection above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [$literal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/)

```
 project("userCount").and("_id").as("user").and("abc").asLiteral().as("extraField")
```

Comment: can you plz take a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45077570/mongodb-aggregation-add-arrays-value-by-value-in-group-step