# MongoDB Aggregation - add arrays (value by value) in group step

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have following collections -

```
    {
        date : "12-Apr-2017",
        empID : "Emp1",
        workDone : [4, 5 9], // ['job A', 'job B', 'Total Jobs']

    },
    {
        date : "12-Apr-2017",
        empID : "Emp2",
        workDone : [2, 5, 7], // ['job A', 'job B', 'Total Jobs']

    },
    {
        date : "13-Apr-2017",
        empID : "Emp1",
        workDone : [6, 4, 10], // ['job A', 'job B', 'Total Jobs']

    }
```

I want output like this -

```
{
    empID : "Emp1",
    workDone : [10, 9, 19] // ['job A', 'job B', 'Total Jobs'] cumulative 

},{
    empID : "Emp2",
    workDone : [2, 5, 7] // ['job A', 'job B', 'Total Jobs'] cumulative 
}
```

How can I add value by value of array in MongoDB aggregation?